# Update a table value to 1, if table IS NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, null

I have a table with alot of fields and I want to summarise the 'completeness' of the data. To do this I plan to write updates to a summary table.

My problem is as follows:

```
Table1 (the data table)
DataID
Data1
Data2

Table2 (the summary table)
DataID
Data1 (NULL YES or NO - 0 or 1)
Data2 (NULL YES or NO - 0 or 1)
```

Basically, I want to run an update query against Table2, that matches the DATAID and then updates the flag to 1 if NOT NULL and 0 if NULL

I know this is fairly basic, but I'm still learning SQL, so please be kind :)

Comment: Are you checking if the data1 and data2 fields are null in **table1**?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE  
 table2 t2, table1 t1  
SET  
 t2.Data1 = IF( t1.Data1 is null, 0, 1 ),  
 t2.Data2 = IF( t1.Data2 is null, 0, 1 )  
WHERE  
 t2.DataID=? and t1.DataID=t2.DataID;
```

Set `?` query parameter with desired `DataID` value.

Comment: `UPDATE   
 Match_Percentage t2, Match_Tables t1   
SET   
 t2.Crowd = IF( t1.Spectators is null, 0, 1 ),      
WHERE   
t1.Serial_No = t2.MATCHID`

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE   
t1.Serial_No = t2.MATCHID' at line 5

Comment: @AndySutton typo error found and corrected. There should not be a comma before where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    table2 a
INNER JOIN
    table1 b ON a.dataID = b.dataID
SET
    a.data1 = b.data1 IS NOT NULL,
    a.data2 = b.data2 IS NOT NULL
WHERE
    a.dataID = ?
```